# Waiting for beta App Review on Testflight

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store, testflight, beta-testing

I had uploaded my App successfully to TestFlight, 5 days ago(with new version and new build number). Which is already uploaded on App Store (But with its Older version).

Now i have added external user to test it and select the build to test and then click on save button, then it is showing "Waiting for beta App Review".

I don't know why user is not added directly rather app goes into "Waiting for beta App Review", and how much time it will take to approve?

Please help me if anyone has faces such issue.

Comment: Its generally takes 1-2 days.

Answer (score 4):

Once you add another user (ie not your apple id), then it must be reviewed by Apple first to ensure the app is safe (contains no malicious intent) for the users testing it.
Normally takes a couple of days for apple to turn around and approve.

Answer (score 0):

There is a distinction between iTunes Connect users and people in TestFlight.

When you upload build, and it shows up, then it becomes visible to your users. But there is an approval process (presumably automated) before TestFlight users see the announcement (assuming it is approved).